# Best practice adding UserControl to parent control via binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I have an `ObservableCollection<ControlMachine>` where each `ControlMachine` is a `UserControl` used to display information about one computer.

```
    public static ObservableCollection<ControlMachine> ListControleMachine =
                        new ObservableCollection<ControlMachine>();
```

I've tried to display the collection using binding

```
   <Grid ForceCursor="True" x:Name="grid2" OpacityMask="{x:Null}" Margin="10,38,10,10" Background="#FFF5F6F6">
       <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListControleMachine}">
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Brush}">
                   <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="3" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100" Fill="blue"/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       </ItemsControl>
   </Grid>
```

My user control is not showing in the `Grid` with this code. What's wrong?

Question: What is the best practice for dispose such ControlMachine one under the others?.

Those ControlMachine can be closed and expanded and I can't find a **clean** way to update the user controls position for any case.

annexe: Do you think it's good-practice using `UserControl` in this case or may be I should use a `Template` or `StackPanel`?

How would you implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for this solution is using a ViewModel instead of UserControl and bind it in your grid.
you can use DependencyProperty and INotifyPropertyChanged for two way binding in your ViewModel.
So you'll not warn about disposing ... .